# select query in where condition based on the main select query values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables like this:
invoice_table

```
╔════╦════════════╦
║ id ║ invoice_id ║
╠════╬════════════╬
║  1 ║     1      ║
║  2 ║     2      ║
║  3 ║     3      ║
╚════╩════════════╩
```

bill_table

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ invoice_id ║bill_amt  ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║     1      ║   50     ║
║  2 ║     1      ║   80     ║  
║  3 ║     2      ║   25     ║
║  4 ║     2      ║   55     ║
║  5 ║     3      ║   60     ║
║  6 ║     3      ║   55     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

credit_table

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ invoice_id ║credit_amt║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║     1      ║   50     ║
║  3 ║     2      ║   25     ║
║  4 ║     2      ║   55     ║
║  5 ║     3      ║   60     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

I need all the invoice_id where (sum(credit_amt of that invoice_id)-sum(bill_amt of that invoice_id)) > 0 
So far i tried this

```
select invoice_id from invoice_table where 
((select sum(bill_amt) FROM bill_table) - (select sum(credit_amt) FROM credit_table)) > 0
```

In other words, I want this result:

```
╔════════════╗
║ invoice_id ║
╠════════════╣
║     1      ║
║     3      ║
╚════════════╝
```

Comment: Certainly, you must have attempted something.

Comment: you must share what you have tried so far

Comment: ya i update that one in my question please wait

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know all accounts that have more billed than credit, not the other way around?

Comment: you are right , but no problem i need that logic @JoachimIsaksson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.invoice_id
FROM invoice_table i 
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT invoice_id, SUM(bill_amt) AS sum_bill_amt 
     FROM bill_table
     GROUP BY invoice_id) b 
    ON i.invoice_id = b.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT invoice_id, SUM(credit_amt) AS sum_credit_amt 
     FROM credit_table
     GROUP BY invoice_id) c 
    ON i.invoice_id = c.invoice_id
WHERE b.sum_bill_amt - c.sum_credit_amt > 0;
```

Comment: Just a note for the OP, the question says `>0` which this answer does correctly, however the expected result requires `<0` which will give your expected result.

Comment: Hi I changed some things and it works thanks@DylanSu

Comment: WHERE (IFNULL(b.sum_bill_amt,0) ) - (IFNULL(c.sum_credit_amt,0)) > 0

Comment: Why the OUTER JOINs?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE invoices;

CREATE TABLE invoices
(invoice_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO invoices VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);

DROP TABLE debits;

CREATE TABLE debits
(debit_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,invoice_id INT NOT NULL
,debit_amount INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO debits VALUES
(1,1,50),
(2,1,80),
(3,2,25),
(4,2,55),
(5,3,60),
(6,3,55);

DROP TABLE credits;

CREATE TABLE credits
(credit_id INT NOT NULL
,invoice_id INT NOT NULL
,credit_amount INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO credits VALUES
(1,1,50),
(3,2,25),
(4,2,55),
(5,3,60);

SELECT i.invoice_id
     , SUM(amount) total 
  FROM invoices i 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT invoice_id, credit_amount * -1 amount FROM credits
       UNION ALL
       SELECT invoice_id, debit_amount FROM debits
     ) x 
    ON x.invoice_id = i.invoice_id 
 GROUP 
    BY i.invoice_id
HAVING total > 0;

+------------+-------+
| invoice_id | total |
+------------+-------+
|          1 |    80 |
|          3 |    55 |
+------------+-------+
```